# Vscode Editor Custom Command Deleting word

Tags: visual-studio-code, workflow, customization

I am attempting to make a custom command that allows me to move words left and right inline by one word at a time. Can anyone help me understand why the command for moving left works as expected, but the command for moving a word to the right is deleting my code? (Image of commands include)

Commands:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+left",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands":[
      "cursorWordLeftSelect",
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "deleteWordEndLeft",
      "cursorWordLeft",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    ]},
    
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+right",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands":[
      "cursorWordRightSelect",
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "deleteWordEndRight",
      "cursorWordRight",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
      "cursorWordLeft",
```

The command for the left movement works perfectly as long as I execute it with a space between the cursor and the word. When using the move right command it works without the "cursorWordLeft" argument but then I have to hit another hotkey to move the cursor to the beginning of the word again which I would like to avoid. Any help appreciated!

[Custom Commands Screenshot][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtXLB.png)

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some general `runCommands` bug, see [editor.action.clipboardPasteAction doesn't work with runCommands](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190831).

Although the issue started with the `clipboardPasteAction` command another person has an issue with different commands.

Your case is particularly interesting in that your left case works fine but the right doesn't - you should add your scenario to the issue (which is being looked at by a vscode team member).

Also interesting is that this keybinding works (it uses a macro extension called `multiCommand`):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+right",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
  // "interval": 100,
    "sequence": [
      "cursorWordRightSelect",
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "deleteWordEndRight",
      "cursorWordRight",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
      "cursorWordLeft"
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that I am NOT using the delay parameter that that extension has available.  It does not seem necessary in this case.

So I really encourage you to keep an eye on the issue and help them out with another use case that is not working.

Comment: That is very interesting, I actually ended up installing that extension and assumed I needed to use the interval key. I assumed that there was a conflict because I was initiating the command using the key “Ctrl” and then some of the mapped commands also use “ctrl” I ended up using the developer: keybind debugger command (paraphrased) and it said it was ignoring Ctrl because it was already in the keydown state